# como adiciona um nome abaixo de uma busca em especifica

Tags: awk

tenho um arquivo com o nome `lista.txt`

```
cat lista.txt
nome1
nome2
nome3
```

agora eu fasso a busca do nome em específico com ***awk***

```
awk '/nome2/' lista.txt
nome2
```

o awk me traz o nome que eu busco!!

agora quero adiciona o nome ***teste*** abaixo desse que eu busquei!

o resultado final que eu quero fica assim!

```
cat lista.txt
nome1
nome2
teste
nome3
```

sei que e possível de outras formas como o uso do ***sed*** por exemplo!

mais quero fazer isso com ***awk***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$ awk '1; /nome2/ {print "teste"}' arquivo.txt
nome1
nome2
teste
nome3
```

- `1;` imprime todas as linhas.
- `/nome2/ {print "teste"}` imprime "teste" quando encontra "nome2".

Comment: muito obrigado! eu tinha tentanto isso antes mais coloquei o 1 depois da ação do print !  percebi que o print adiciona o nome teste com uma quebra de linha \n !  isso e padrão?  achei que ele colocaria de lado !

Comment: @socketplus sem quebra de linha é com `printf`.